# Knockout-sortable - Multiple Elements In List Item

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable, knockout-sortable

I am working off of the following example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWgRF/715/) and changed it to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWgRF/815/)

I am attempting to change it to allow multiple elements bound to an object in an array, however no matter what I do, only the first element with data-bind is rendered. I am sure that I am using it wrong, however I do not understand why I am wrong.

Shouldn't the following render two labels, the first with the name and the second with the ID?

```
<div class="list">
    <h2>Stored procedures In DB 2</h2>
    <ul class="list" id="sortableForDB_2" data-bind="sortable: storedProceduresInDB2">
        <li><div><label class="item" data-bind="text: Name" />
                 <label class="item" data-bind="text: Id" /></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Edit 1: By the way, it is definitely something to do with the data-bind as the following works just fine:

```
<div class="list">
    <h2>Stored procedures In DB 2</h2>
    <ul class="list" id="sortableForDB_2" data-bind="sortable: storedProceduresInDB2">
        <li><div><label>1</label>
                 <label>2</label></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `label` element must be correctly formed for the bindings to work - ie it must have a closing tag:

```
<div class="list">
    <h2>Stored procedures In DB 2</h2>
    <ul class="list" id="sortableForDB_2" data-bind="sortable: storedProceduresInDB2">
        <li><div><label class="item" data-bind="text: Name"></label>
            <label class="item" data-bind="text: Id"></label></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWgRF/818/)

Regarding the correct formation of the [`label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> Tag omission:  None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.

Comment: We've all been there :)